# Java Luhn check/credit card validation

Tags: java

I have been given this assignment to write a program to validate credit card numbers based on modulus operator. I have worked on this for hours to get it to where it is  however its not validating correctly. Its probably the math but Im not sure. It either comes back all valid or all invalid. Please see my code below and let me know what I am missing. PS im a noob so my code is not top notch.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Credit_Card_eval {
    public static int  Evaluation(int x) {
        if (x%10==0) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
        return 0;
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int OddSum=0;
        int DoubSum=0;
        int FinalSum=0;
        int Count=0;
   
        int Answer;
   
        String Result;

        System.out.println("Please enter your credit card number");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        int[] CC = new int[16];
      
        try {
            for (int i=0;i<=15;i++) {
                Count++;
                CC[i] = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i));    
                //Getting Credit Card Numbers from user

                if (CC[i]!=16) {
                    throw new ArithmeticException ("Your input is invalid, please enter a credit card number that is atleast 16 numbers");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
      
        for (int i=0; i<1;i++) {                                                
            if(CC[0]==4)
                System.out.println("Your Card is a Visa Card and it is ");
            else if (CC[0]==5)
                System.out.println("Your Card is a Master Card and it is ");
            else if (CC[0]==3 && CC[1]==7)
                System.out.println("Your Card is an American Express and it is ");
            else if (CC[0]==6)
                System.out.println("Your Card is a Discover Card and it is ");
            else
                System.out.println("Your Card is a Unknown Card and it is ");
        }
    
        for (int i = CC.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            CC[i] += CC[i];
        }     //Step 1. Doubling every second digit from right to left. 
        for (int i = CC.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if(CC[i]>=10) CC[i]+=CC[i]-9;
        }  //Separating Double digit numbers
        for (int i=0;i<=CC.length;i++) {
            DoubSum = DoubSum+i;
        }                       //Step 2. Add all single-digit numbers from Step 1. 
        for (int i=0;i<CC.length;i++) {
            if (i%2!=0) {
                OddSum = OddSum+i;
            }
        }                 //Step 3. Adding odd numbers from left to right
  
        FinalSum = DoubSum+OddSum;                                                 
        //Step 4.Sum the results from Step 2 and Step 3. 
     
        System.out.println(Evaluation(FinalSum));                                     
        //Step 5. Valid or invalid checker   
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is your criteria for validation?

Comment: Its to mod the result of step 4. If the result is 0 it should be valid else invalid

Comment: Do you think the issue is with step 2  for (int i=0;i<CC.length;i++) {
            if (i%2!=0) {
                OddSum = OddSum+i;

Comment: If you need to remove the question, just delete it. Don't vandalize it.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a few sites that have an easy to use RegEx for validation. Check out: 
https://howtodoinjava.com/regex/java-regex-validate-credit-card-numbers/

Comment: thanks man but I am trying to make one for my self with but the coding is giving me an issue. I know sites are out there but I dont want to take the easy way out. Just want to understand.